# How to fit Text to container without using FittedBox

Tags: flutter, dart

When using FittedBox, the text size gets very small compared to the text length.
I don't want the text to shrink. Instead I want the text to stay the same size and fit only the part that can fit.

```
Container(
 width: 250,
 child: Text("Data will end with ... instead of shrinking..."),),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your text to work this way, you should set how text behaves in case of overflow.

What you need to do, is set the `overflow` property to `TextOverflow.ellipsis`:

```
Text(
  'Hello, Test! How are you?',
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
)
```

It is provided in the Flutter documentation of the `Text` widget: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html.

Also, check other text overflow options: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextOverflow.html

Comment: I have to check the website before I open a thread. It's my fault. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Flexible`

```
Container(
  child: Row(
  children: [
    Flexible(child: Text("A looooooooooooooooooong text"))
  ],
 ),
),
```

For more info about `Flexible` check
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same challenge, in my Agric app showing weather forecasts to the famers, tried several alternatives but couldn't find a better solution other than using FittedBox.
FittedBox has a BoxFit property which align the source within the target box (by default, centering) and, if necessary, scale the source down to ensure that the source fits within the box.
This is the same as contain if that would shrink the image, otherwise it is the same as none.

```
FittedBox(
    fit:BoxFit.scaleDown,
    child: Text("hey, how are you",
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    maxLines: 1,
    style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4))),
    )
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?